# Why does Parquet file size get smaller when copied with Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a Hive partitioned table populated by Hive and stored on S3 as Parquet. The data size for a specific partition is 3GB. Then I make a copy with Athena with:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_partition
AS SELECT *
FROM original_table
where hour=11
```

The resulting data size is less than half (1.4GB). What could be the reason?

EDIT: related hive table definition statement:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://...'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compress'='SNAPPY', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1558011438'
)
```

Comment: What are the default compression codecs on source & target?

Answer (score 1):

Different compression settings is one possible explanation. If your original files were not compressed or compressed with Snappy that could explain it. If you don't specify what compression to use Athena will default to gzip, which compresses better than Snappy.

If you want a more thorough answer than that you will have to give us some more details. How did you create the original files, are they compressed, what compression, what does the data look like, etc.

Comment: The original files were created by Hive (Tez engine if it matters). The table definition specified snappy compression.I think the Athena files are also using snappy; can I tell for sure by inspecting the files?
EDIT: updated the question with relevant table definition

Comment: If you created the new files with the statement in your question they are gzip-compressed, that's the default. I assume that the definition you added is the source table. You can verify this by downloading one of the files and use for example `parquet-tools` to check the files: `parquet-tools meta path/to/file`. That will tell you what compression was used..

Comment: You're right; not only are the Athena files gzip but the original ones are uncompressed! Sample column:

publisher:             BINARY UNCOMPRESSED DO:0 FPO:117676892 SZ:899708/899708/1.00 VC:705318 ENC:RLE,BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[no stats for this column]
vs

publisher:             BINARY GZIP DO:0 FPO:714686 SZ:695050/918981/1.32 VC:667230 ENC:BIT_PACKED,RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[no stats for this column]

Now the question becomes why the original ones are not compressed to Snappy despite the table definition

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, consider marking it as the correct answer.